# paypal express checkout button redirecting to cart page in magento 1.9.1

Tags: paypal, paypal-express, magento-1.9.1.1

When i purchase a product then on cart page after click on paypal checkout button it redirects from cart page to cart page again instead of redirecting to paypal .Why this happens. I am using same paypal express to my another site there it work fine .This issue occur i migrate my site from shared server to dedicated server...
This is the extension.log file errors
[image]

Comment: What happens if you disable the `Magestore_Onestepcheckout` module ?

Comment: when i disable onestepcheckout my dashboard gets blank

Answer (score 0):

```
Invalid block type: Mage_Tco_Block_Iframe
Invalid block type: Mage_Wirecard_Checkout_Page_Block_Seamless_Script
```

These two lines from your error log suggest Magento isn't able to find your custom blocks (because it is prepending `Mage_` to the front).  Check that permissions on your files are correct and the custom extensions are enabled.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155051/why-is-magento-trying-to-call-in-the-mage-namespace-rather-than-my-custom-namesp